# Search URL from Database using regular expression in SQL-Query

Tags: sql, preg-match

I want to search a URL "www.google.co.in/" from database table. When I search adding "google.co.in/" even then my Query is not able to search and find it record because 'www' is not added. 
So i want to use regular expression in query which help to search only 'google.co.in' from the table (it  doesnot mater whether http or www is added or not)

For now I am using a simple `LIKE` operator to search:
`SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_value LIKE '%www.google.co.in/%'`

Comment: I tried to edit your question properly. Please be so kind and clarify what your issue is.

Comment: @Snickbrack i have edited please check.

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with PHP, I suggest removing this tag and adding the specific tag of the database. If that's MySQL then there is a [regex syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html) in there.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to search like this:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_value LIKE '%google.co.in%'
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_value LIKE '%google%'
```

Comment: text google.com or www.ggogle.com will be dynamic content which will be added by users. so we cannot check condition like you have mentioned